# Incomplete Type with header

Tags: c, linker, header-files

I have a header file:

#### Location.h

```
#ifndef LOCATION_H
#define LOCATION_H

#define MAX_X_GRID (3)
#define MAX_Y_GRID (3)

typedef struct _location Location;

extern Location *Location_create();
extern void Location_destroy(Location *);

#endif /* LOCATION_H */
```

.. a soure file:

#### Location.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Location.h"

#define VALID_LOCATION_CODE (245)
#define _location_check(l) \
    if ( l == NULL || l->_Valid != VALID_LOCATION_CODE ) \
        abort();

struct _location
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int _Valid;
};

struct _location *Location_create(const int x, const int y)
{
    if (x > MAX_X_GRID || y > MAX_Y_GRID)
        return NULL;

    struct _location *l = malloc(sizeof(struct _location));
    if (l == NULL)
        return NULL;
    l->x = x;
    l->y = y;
    l->_Valid = VALID_LOCATION_CODE;
    return l;
}

void Location_destroy(struct _location *l)
{
    _location_check(l);
    free(l);
}
```

.. and I am testing the code like that:

#### test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Location.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Location *l = Location_create(1, 2);
    printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", l->x, l->y); /* line 6 */
    Location_destroy(l);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program with this command:

> gcc test.c -o test -Wall

I get these errors:

> test.c:6:27: error: trying to dereference a pointer of incomplete type
>
> // line 6
>
> test.c:6:33: error: trying to dereference a pointer of incomplete type
>
> // line 6

From the errors, it seems that gcc is not aware of the header file I included.

What can I do to fix that ?

Comment: You did a great job asking the question in detail, but "some errors" part ruined everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Location.h` doesn't disclose the contents of the `struct _location` (type is incomplete), so while compiling `test.c` gcc has no clue what `l->x` and `l->y` are.

Comment: So .. when I declare the struct in Location.c, I have to provide wrapper functions like: `Location_get_x` and `Location_get_y`, but when I declare it in Location.h, does that allow me to access struct members directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `struct` and `function declarations` (not definitions) into the header. E.g. move the following into the header file:

```
#ifndef LOCATION_H
#define LOCATION_H

#define MAX_X_GRID (3)
#define MAX_Y_GRID (3)

typedef struct _location Location;

struct _location
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int _Valid;
};

struct _location *Location_create(const int x, const int y);
void Location_destroy(struct _location *l);

#endif /* LOCATION_H */
```